# Is it possible to add an iFrame tab to an existing Facebook page?

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, facebook-iframe

The recent Facebook update (timeline etc) seems to have changed how to add an iFrame tab to a page. There are lots of questions relating to this issue already, but none that I can see which have been asked/answered since the recent update in September 2011.

I want to be able to add an iFrame to my existing Facebook page. My understanding is that I can put a page on my server (e.g. at foo.com/facebook), with CSS and even JavaScript running there. I then specify foo.com/facebook in the Facebook Developer app, and users will then see the page that is hosted on my site, in an iFrame on the Facebook page.

I have been to the Facebook Developer application and I can see how to add the URL etc for a *new* application. However I want to add this to an *existing* Facebook page. I've found a few posts relating to this, such this one:

http://www.facebook.com/notes/hyperarts-web-design/adding-an-iframe-application-to-your-facebook-fan-page-2011/10150145148215844

It explains how to associate an application with any page that you are an admin of (see "Installing your iFrame application on your Fan Page"). This is exactly what I want to do.

However, with the recent update, the ability to associate an app with any page that you are an admin of (as opposed to the page that is created when you create the application) seems to have disappeared. So now, it seems like my only option is to start a whole new page along with the new application. This is not good, because all the people who like my existing page will not start liking the new page just because I've put a fancy new iFrame tab there (plus I don't want to change the vanity URL I've secured for the existing page).

The only way round it that I can see is to add an application like http://iframes.wildfireapp.com to my existing Facebook page, and then add some custom HTML. But this is not really what I want because I'd have to put all my CSS inline with the HTML, plus I wouldn't be able to use any Javascript.

Even if I can't use Javascript it would be really nice if I could just specify the URL on my site rather than make all my styling inline (which would be an ongoing pain in the ass to update versus just updating it like the rest of my website with normal stylesheets).

Any help appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Applications do, themselves, have Pages as you mention. However this is more of an informational page about the app.

What you seem to be wanting to do is add a new custom tab to your page. All tabs are applications; when you use wildfire or [static html](https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=190322544333196), your using their pre-existing app and putting your content in it. And as you point out this can have limitations (a frequently overlooked one is the lack of a custom 16x16 app icon).

The way to do what you want is:

1. Create a new FB app in the [Facebook Developer Console](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) pointing at your IFrame.
2. When editing the FB app, click the link on the left "View App Profile Page" (under "Related links")
3. This takes you the (largely useless) app profile page.
4. On the left, click "Add to My Page"
5. Select the page from the dialog.
6. Go to the page, edit it and make sure the tab is visible.

Comment: Fantastic, that's exactly what I want to do. Thanks for your help.